# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251 when update data laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

This question is about to edit my data in my table. the view or the form has shown perfectly. but when i edit my data and press update button, it show MethodNotAllowedHttpException error. Did my Method wrong?

this is the view

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" action="{{action('AdminController@updateruang', $id_ruang)}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="item form-group">
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">ID Ruangan <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="title" name="title" value="{{$ruang->id_ruang}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Nama Ruangan <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="title" name="title" value="{{$ruang->nm_ruang}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Keterangan <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="title" name="title" value="{{$ruang->keterangan}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
  </form>
```

This is the AdminController

```
public function updateruang(Request $request, $id_ruang)
{
    $ruang = Ruang::find($id_ruang);
    $ruang->nm_ruang = $request->get('nm_ruang');
    $ruang->keterangan = $request->get('keterangan');
    $ruang->save();

    return redirect('/admin/dataruang')->with('success', 'New data has been updated!!');
}
```

This is the route

```
Route::post('/editdataruang{id_ruang}','AdminController@updateruang', function(){
    $users[] = Auth::user();
    $users[] = Auth::guard()->user();
    $users[] = Auth::guard('admin')->user();

})->name('editdataruang');
```

Comment: `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">` so define your route as such.

Comment: add slash here `'/editdataruang/{id_ruang}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is like this - in your code form you have:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

but your route is defined as

```
Route::post('/editdataruang{id_ruang}','AdminController@updateruang', function(){
```

So either remove line:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

from form or change:

```
Route::post('/editdataruang{id_ruang}','AdminController@updateruang', function(){
```

into

```
Route::patch('/editdataruang{id_ruang}','AdminController@updateruang', function(){
```

Assuming you are making update you should rather change the route from `post` to `patch` instead of removing line from form.